# Testing my Rake task in Rails 4 loses an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I can't get my Rake task test to pass; it seems that after the rake task has run I lose my instance variable as it returns nil whereas before the Rake task is run I get a record

So before all my tests I have this config setup

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'
load File.expand_path('../../lib/tasks/create_events.rake', __FILE__)
load File.expand_path('../../lib/tasks/update_event.rake', __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
   Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
   Rake::Task['create_events:create_event_data'].invoke
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

My spec file is setup like so

```
require "rails_helper"
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe "update_event:next_event_date Rake Task" do

 it "should change the next occurrence date" do
  @update_event = Event.where(next_occurrence: Date.today)
  # So here @update_event returns 1 record (Active Record Relation)
  Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  Rake::Task['update_event:next_event_date'].invoke
  # By here @update_event = nil (Active Record Relation = [])

   case @update_event.first.weekly_frequency
   when 1
    expect(@update_event.first.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 7.days)
   when 2
    expect(@update_event.first.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 14.days)
   when 6
    expect(@update_event.first.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 42.days)
   end
 end
end
```

What is the reason behind this and how do I test this correctly?

My actual Rake task is this

```
namespace :update_event do
 desc "Update next_occurrence date for an event"
  task next_event_date: :environment do
   @event = Event.where(next_occurrence: Date.today)
    @event.each do |e|
     if e.weekly_frequency == 1
      e.update_attributes next_occurrence: Date.today + 7.days
     elsif e.weekly_frequency == 2
      e.update_attributes next_occurrence: Date.today + 14.days
     elsif e.weekly_frequency == 6
      e.update_attributes next_occurrence: Date.today + 42.days
     end
   end
  end
 end
```

### Edit

So I have modified my spec slightly to this

```
require "rails_helper"
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe "update_event:next_event_date Rake Task" do

it "should change the next occurrence date" do
  @update_event = Event.where(next_occurrence: Date.today)
  event_id = Event.find(@update_event.first.id)
  Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  Rake::Task['update_event:next_event_date'].invoke
  @after_update = Event.find(event_id)
   case @after_update.weekly_frequency
   when 1
    expect(@after_update.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 7.days)
   when 2
    expect(@after_update.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 14.days)
   when 6
    expect(@after_update.next_occurrence).to eq(Date.today + 42.days)
  end
 end    
end
```

This passes but I'm not sure why I lose my first instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not "losing" your instance variable. Your instance variable is a query which will yield different results before and after your rake task. Your modified test executes the query before the rake task and saves something derived from the result in a local variable (i.e. the id of the first record). You could achieve a similar effect by saving the event as follows:

```
@update_event = Event.find_by(next_occurrence: Date.today)
```

since `find_by` returns an `ActiveRecord` not an `ActiveRelation`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, maybe I'm just a bit confused then as I thought the point at which I took a record from the db and assigned it to @update_event was before I ran my rake task?

Comment: Nope. `where` returns a query object (i.e. an `ActiveRelation`) which doesn't execute until you call a method on it which performs the execution (such as `first` or `all`).

Comment: Wow, did not know that, well that clears everything up, thank you